# Не вешается hover background rgba на картинку

Tags: html, css

что я делаю не так? не работает и все тут :( нужно при наведении что бы на картинку накладывался цвет. Я наверное не знаю хитрость :)

```css
img:hover {
 background: rgba(39,156,232, 0.5);
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="head_block"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-360-260-1.jpg" alt="" width="360" height="260"></div>
```

Comment: В хроме все работает

Comment: @Arcadiy странно очень, у меня тоже заработало здесь, но на моем index.html это не работает =\, вот глянь, я повесил картинку, hover перестал работать

Comment: либо мне попробовать img вставить именно в сss и там уже мудрить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.head_block
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.head_block img, .overlay 
{
    width: 360px;
    height: 240px;
}

.overlay
{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.overlay:hover 
{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 234, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="head_block">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
    <img src="http://s5.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/08/20/7/1440069505_326762601.png"" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: супер, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сделать

```css
img:hover {
 background: rgba(39,156,232, 0.5);
 cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="head_block"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-360-260-1.jpg" alt="" width="360" height="260"></div>
```

Comment: Не думаю, что решение верно. 
Вы меняете прозрачность самой картинки, что ни есть верно (под картинкой могут быть другие элементы, например), хотя автор указал, что цвет должен накладываться. 
Важно, что если выполнить подобный код, то вне зависимости от установленного цвета результат не изменится.